# Questions about the Gateaux derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces

We defined that a function is Gateaux differentiable, if all directional derivatives exist.
I just wanted to check, whether I got a few things right:
Now I wanted to ask, whether it is true that if $(x_0,h) \mapsto d(x_0,h)$ is continuous, then $df(x_0,.)$ is linear?

and if $df(x_0,.)$ is bounded and linear and $x_0 \mapsto d(x_0,.)$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuously Frechet-differentiable.

I am just asking this, because from this, we would have that if $(x_0,h) \mapsto d(x_0,h)$ is continuous then $f$ is continuously Frechet-differentiable and I am not sure whether this is true.

I think this wikipedia article covers some of the questions I am asking, but maybe you could recheck whether every I said is true? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative#Linearity_and_continuity

Comment: The most useful definition requires $D_Gf(x_0)$ to be a continuous linear operator. For some Authors, however, the mere existence of $$\left. \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon=0} f(x_0+\varepsilon h)$$ is required, for every $h$.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately we use the last definition.

Comment: I can't provide a counterexample, but **Theorem 2.1.13** of M. Berger, *Nonlinearity and functional analys* states that, if $f$ is G-differentiable, if the G-derivative is linear and depends continuously on the point of differentiation, then $f$ is F-differentiable. I do not believe that the linearity assumption is written just for fun ;-)